# How to make an alias to enclose multi-member expression passed as argument to a perl script

Tags: zsh

I spent a long time searching but cannot find the answer.

I am using an ["astronomy-aware" perl script](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/%7Ealexey/calc-src.txt) which is super useful for calculations on the command line and in scripts. The problem is that parentheses have to be escaped:

```
calc.pl (1+1)/(2+2)   
zsh: unknown file attribute: 2

calc.pl \(1+1\)/\(2+2\)
0.5
```

The best alternative to escaping each one is using single quotes to enclose the entire expression like this:

```
calc.pl '(1+1) / (2+2)'
0.5
```

How can I define a zsh alias (like `alias calc="${HOME}/bin/calc.pl"`) that encloses the expression that comes after the call to the script within the single quotes as shown in the second example?

Comment: You're missing the point of the quotes. It's for the benefit of the shell. The shell is the one that needs the quotes or escapes. So there's no solution to your question. // Also, you say bash and you tagged bash, but you're apparently using zsh. huh?

Comment: Aliases can't change the text after the alias.

Comment: @Barmar Re "*Aliases can't change the text after the alias.*", But functions can. This is not the issue.

Comment: @ikegami No they can't. The arguments are parsed before the function is called.

Comment: However this may be useful: https://superuser.com/questions/1508079/auto-quote-arguments-in-zsh

Comment: @Barmar Re "*No they can't.*", Sure they can. /// Re "*The arguments are parsed before the function is called.*", Yes, and that is the issue.

Comment: Please post an answer showing how to do it then @ikegami

Comment: @Barmar, That's not the question asks to do. I already noted how what the question asks to do is impossible.

Comment: @ikegami Then I don't understand why you're contradicting me, I'm saying the same thing. There's no way to auto-quote the arguments.

Comment: That's not what you said

Comment: It's what I *thought* I said :)

Answer (score 3):

The solution linked by Barmar works! Thank you so much!

It was provided by ([aloxaf](https://superuser.com/users/921237/aloxaf)) here:
https://superuser.com/questions/1508079/auto-quote-arguments-in-zsh

I defined the following in my `.zshrc` and it works.

```
function quote-accept-line() {
    local -a starts_with=("calc.pl ")
    for str ($starts_with) {
        if [[ ${(M)BUFFER#$str} ]] {
            BUFFER=$str${(qq)BUFFER#$str}
        }
    }
    zle accept-line
}
zle -N quote-accept-line
# bind it to "Enter"
bindkey "^M" quote-accept-line
```

Comment: Important note: as @ikegami pointed out, this function works in zsh, but doesn't work in bash.

Answer (score 0):

The special `noglob` command modifier can be used for this:

```
% calc.pl (1+1) / (2+2)
zsh: unknown file attribute: 1

% noglob calc.pl (1+1) / (2+2)
0.5
```

Typing `noglob` all the time will probably get boring fast, so you can create an alias for this in your zshrc:

```
% alias calc.pl='noglob calc.pl'
% calc.pl (1+1) / (2+2)
0.5
```

The difference between the "auto quoter" is that something like this:

```
% calc.pl 2' * 3
```

won't work, as the quotes are still interpreted. I have never run in to issues with this though, as I can't recall ever having used quotes in a calculation, but maybe your Perl script accepts some syntax for that.

Either way, it's a much simpler solution which is *probably* enough for your purpose.

---

Bonus: zsh comes with the `zcalc` module, which provides a calculator; I have no idea how this compares to your Perl script, but the way I have this set up is like this:

```
autoload -U zcalc                     # Get quick results for "zc 6 * 6", or just use "zc" to get zcalc
alias zc >/dev/null && unalias zc
zc() { if (( $# )); then zcalc -e ${(j: :)@}; else zcalc; fi }
alias zc='noglob zc'
```

By default `zcalc` will throw you in to a REPL unless you use `-e`, which I find a bit annoying; this way you can type `zc (1.0+1) / (2+2)` and get your results quickly.

Answer (score -3):

[*The question originally asked for a bash solution and was originally tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash).*]

You're missing the point of the quotes or escapes. It's for the benefit of the shell, not `calc.pl`. (`calc.pl` doesn't even see them; it gets `(1+1)/(2+2)` when you execute the shell command `calc.pl \(1+1\)/\(2+2\)`.)

The issue is that `( ... )` and spaces have special meaning to the shell, so escapes and/or quotes are used to change how the shell interprets them.

You can't do anything about that after the shell has already interpreted them incorrectly, so your request has no solution.

[*While the above is still true in zsh, one can hook into zsh's command line editor as shown in the other answer. This allows the command to be edited before zsh sees it.*]

Comment: The function defined above works perfectly well to capture whatever comes after "calc.pl " and automatically enclose in quotes the expression before sending it for interpretation. Meaning, I don't type the single quotes, but the moment I press enter they appear. Like magic :)

Comment: 1) All those changes are done before the shell sees the command, just like I said was necessary. It literally changes the editor. 2) The other answer doesn't work in bash, which is what the OP had requested.